# Import Test data from Excel sheet into selenium java code

Tags: selenium, import, xlsx

Below is the code to create a FB account. I have excel sheet with Test data to create them. How to import that data into the below code???

**Code:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;


public class Facebookup {

public static void main (String args[]) throws InterruptedException
{

    WebDriver gm = new FirefoxDriver();

    gm.manage().window().maximize();

    gm.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

    gm.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_1']")).sendKeys("Tester");
    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_3']")).sendKeys("Dravid");
    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_5']")).sendKeys("testprod2000@gmail.com");
    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_8']")).sendKeys("testprod2000@gmail.com");
    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_a']")).sendKeys("Naren1234");
    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='month']")).click();

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//option[@value = '1']")).click();
    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='day']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//option[@value = '8']")).click();
    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='year']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//option[@value = '1991']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_e']")).click();
    gm.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_i']")).click();





 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JXL Java library which has a method to read data from excel sheets. 
The jar can be downloaded from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjxljar.htm